# Identify all repositories which just have a master branch

Tags: git, github

We have a large number of repositories maintained in our Github account. Is there a way to retrieve all repos which are defaulting and just have a master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script and check default branch. For example:

```sh
$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos?per_page=1000' | grep 'default_branch'
"default_branch": "master"
# ..
# ..
# ..
```

This will print the default branch name. You can then filter out only relevant repos and have something like:

```sh
repos=$(...)
echo "$repos" | while read line ; do
   git clone "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a large query to be executed on GitHub, the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) is a good candidate.

[This gist](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/graphql/queries/repo-get-all-branches.graphql) illustrates how to get all branches for a repository.
You can nest it inside this other [GraphQL query](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/graphql/queries/branches-and-commits-by-repository.graphql) which will fetch all repositories inside an organization.

(not tested: just to give an idea: can be tweaked in the [GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer))

```yaml
query getCommitsByBranchByRepo($org:String!, $repo:String!) {
  organization(login:$org) {
    name
    repository(name:$repo) {
      name
      refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            branchName:name
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          endCursor #use this value to paginate through repos with more than 100 branches
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The idea is to have *one* client-side query to execute, instead of possibly a large number of `curl`, possibly triggering limits on the number of HTTP requests accepted by GitHub from one IP.